# AEM components height and width (dimensions)

Tags: aem

I've used card/image components on the page
sometimes 2 cards in a row or 3 cards in a row
some of them contain images in them and I want to know the dimension(height and width) of image that can be dragged and dropped in those components without the image getting cropped. how can I find that out through properties?
thanks in advance.